# How to store byte array in HBase using thrift C++ API (value in Mutation Struct is Text ...)

Tags: c++, hbase, thrift

I want store file in HBase with C++.

But HBase Thrift Api doesn't support byte array ... only support Text (string).

How do I Store file in HBase using C++?

Answer (score 4):

You may have solved this by now but I had a similar issue and resolved it by constructing a string from the entire byte array that I had. And then set it as a value in the mutation.

```
// dbytes is the byte array
std::string valStr;
valStr.assign(std::begin(dbytes), std::end(dbytes));
mutations.back().value = valStr;
```

Comment: Yes, in C++ `std::string` is actually commonly used for "byte array."